# Please explain why x is 2

Tags: java, unary-operator

```
x = 100;
x = x-- - --x;
```

x is 2 when printed.

I'm confused.
I thought it will be evaluated like this.

```
x = 100 - 99;
```

Isn't it supposed to be 1?

Comment: The two sides are not evaluated simultaneously, after evaluating `x--` the value of `x` has already changed

Comment: It is `100 - 98`. `x--` decrements `x` from `100` to `99` and returns the value it had before the operation, so `100`. `--x` decrements from `99` to `98` and returns the value after the operation, so `98`. Yielding `100 - 98` which is `2`. The key is: `x--` does **not** decrement **after** some time, but immediately. However, the operation returns the value before decrement. So `x` is always modified immediately.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess that made sense. I guess the confusing part is that x-- already changed x at --x.  Thanks! I can finally sleep better tonight.